# FFmpeg package for Apple Silicon

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, build

I'm in the process of porting all of our code to Apple M1 (ARM), and some of our products use FFmpeg.
Are there any library packages by FFmpeg that are built for the Apple Silicon M1, and where can I find them?

Comment: If you have a M1 mac then you can try to compile it on your own. I have published a [build script](https://gitlab.com/marty-media/ffmpeg) running on MacOS (not tested with Apple Silicon).

Comment: @martinr92 thanks for the link! However I was hoping there would be a package optimized and tested specifically for the M1 rather than having every one build it for oneself.

Comment: @martinr92 I got build failed error while compiling aom because of an error: "--enable-runtime-cpu-detect selected, but no CPU detection method " "available for your platform. Reconfigure with --disable-runtime-cpu-detect."

Comment: Update: According to https://www.toolfarm.com/news/apple-silicon-compatibility/ `ffmpeg` now has full native support.

Comment: "brew install ffmpeg" works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like there's a working script and a built version now available at https://www.osxexperts.net

Answer (score 8):

You can compile ffmpeg for Apple Silicon by yourself.
For this you will need Xcode, which comes with all the necessary tools.

You can download Xcode [from the App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12), [from Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), or install the Xcode command line tools running `xcode-select --install` on the Terminal app.

After getting Xcode, you need to open it once to accept the terms and set up everything. You will be asked for your computer password.

After setting up Xcode, execute the following commands in that order, on the Terminal app, as a normal user (root is not necessary and not recommended). Lines beginning with `#` are comments and you should not execute them on the terminal.

```
# Create and go to a folder where you'll save the ffmpeg source code
mkdir -p /opt/local/src
cd /opt/local/src

# get the ffmpeg source code from the official source
git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg

# set up build and begin to compile
./configure --prefix=/opt/local
make
make install

# check that your compiled version of ffmpeg has arm64 (Apple Silicon) architecture
/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -version
```